# Замена Viber со связью через мой сервер

Tags: поиск-программ

Есть ли какие то решения, которые позволят мне общаться с другим человеком как в Viber'е, т.е. голос, видео, демонстрация экрана, но с поднятием своего сервера и связью только через него? Желательно чтобы для проверки работы можно было временно развернуть сервер на обычном windows-компьютере.

Comment: Nextcloud Talk?

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрим.